# Java: right justify with Format class doesn't work

Tags: java, text-justify

I want to right-justify this simple text file (line length is 80) with Format class:

**Each white-space is [TAB]**

```
|Text|EOL                                                                   
|   Text    Text|EOL                                                        
|       Text    Text    Text|EOL                                            
|           Text    Text    Text    Text|EOL                                
|               Text    Text    Text    Text    Text|EOL                    
|                   Text    Text    Text    Text    Text    Text|EOL        
|                       Text    Text    Text    Text    Text    Text|EOL    
|                           Text    Text    Text    Text    Text    Text|EOL
```

Here is the code I wrote:

```
public static void justify(){
    try(
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Szymon\\Desktop\\textfile.txt"));
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("C:\\Users\\Szymon\\Desktop\\textout.txt")
    ) {
        while(in.ready()){
            String line = in.readLine();

            out.format("%80s\n", line.trim()); // ?
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

but the output is not what I've expected:

```
|                                                                            Text|EOL
|                                                                      Text Text|EOL
|                                                                  Text Text    Text|EOL
|                                                             Text  Text    Text    Text|EOL
|                                                        Text   Text    Text    Text    Text|EOL
|                                                   Text    Text    Text    Text    Text    Text|EOL
|                                                   Text    Text    Text    Text    Text    Text|EOL
|                                                   Text    Text    Text    Text    Text    Text|EOL
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: And what do you expect? We don't have enough information here to help you, really...  Are you looking at it in a fixed-width font?

Comment: Are there tab characters in the input?

Comment: @rgettman yes, I updated the input information - I hope it helps.

Comment: Then you'll have to account for the fact that a tab character takes up more than one character's worth of space.

Comment: @rgettman Hm... does it really matter ? My idea was to trim white-spaces around and just justify.

Comment: Yes, the tabs that are in between your text words do not get trimmed.